# How get a client credentials with Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, request

I am new on **NodeJs** and I would like to use a job API, but I need to get firstly the **access_token** (client credentials), so I try to `POST` my `CLIENT_ID` & `CLIENT_SECRET` to get that, but I think I made some mistakes in my code:

According to the [doc](https://pole-emploi.io/data/documentation/utilisation-api-pole-emploi/generer-access-token), I tried to reproduce the order of the property, so i tried this :

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();

app.get ("/test", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await genrateAccessToken();
  console.log(data);
  res.json(data);
});


async function genrateAccessToken() {
  axios.post('https://authentification-candidat.pole-emploi.fr/connexion/oauth2/access_token'{
     header : {
      'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
     body: {
      grant_type: client_credentials,
      client_id: 'Client_ID',
      client_secret: 'Client_Secret',
      scope: 'api_labonneboitev1'
    }
    

});
   return response.data;
}

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port `)
})
```

Comment: Can you post the error that you are facing ? what is happening when genrateAccessToken runs ?

Comment: @yatin-gupta i got `axios.post('https://authentification-candidat.pole-emploi.fr/connexion/oauth2/access_token'{        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @Thestrike95 You're just missing a comma...

Comment: `client_credentials` should at least be a string.

Comment: @Brad i add the comma but is still show me the same error

Comment: @Evert on the docs, he does not put it

Comment: @Thestrike95 then the docs are wrong, unless you have a variable somewhere called 'client_credentials' with that value.

Answer (score 0):

[By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON](https://axios-http.com/docs/urlencoded), but you are setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is not JSON.

To URL encode the body, you could do:

```js
body: new URLSearchParams({
  grant_type: client_credentials,
  client_id: 'Client_ID',
  client_secret: 'Client_Secret',
  scope: 'api_labonneboitev1'
})
```

Or, if this API really does want JSON, then you would set the `Content-Type` to `application/json`.

Whether the API accepts JSON, urlencoded, or something else, is up to it. But the bottom line is, you have to figure out what format this API accepts, set the `Content-Type` header accordingly, *and* format the body accordingly.

Comment: I fix that part but i have still a same error come from my **url** 